# Linux command symbol !ls meaning

Tags: command-line, ls

What is the meaning of ! in a command?
For example ls command, what is the output after put in from of it (!ls)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means to run the last command in your history list that begins with `ls` as it was pointed out to me.  If you last ran a command of `lsb_release` then that would be ran.  If you ran just the command `ls` it would give you the directory listing.  It runs the last or most recent command that starts with whatever you specify.

If you run `history` on your system you will see all the commands that you have ran.  And if you wanted a specific command from your history it would be `!#` like `!1990` would run my previous command of `cd`.

*Example history output:*

```
 1990  cd
 1991  sync
 1992  ssh pi@10.0.0.201
 1993  sync
 1994  sync
 1995  sudo apt autoremove
 1996  reboot
 1997  sudo apt remove nvidia-driver-430
 1998  sudo apt install nvidia-driver-435
 1999  sudo apt autoremove
 2000  reboot
 2001  ./intrepid_check.bsh 
 2002  ssh intrepid
 2003  ls -al
 2004  ls
 2005  ls -al
 2006  history
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$
```

And if I wanted to run the last `ssh` command on that list I type it in as

```
!ssh
```

*Example:*

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ !ssh
ssh intrepid
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.0.0-29-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

 * Congrats to the Kubernetes community on 1.16 beta 1! Now available
   in MicroK8s for evaluation and testing, with upgrades to RC and GA

     snap info microk8s

 * Canonical Livepatch is enabled.
   - All available patches applied.

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2023.
You have mail.
Last login: Wed Sep 25 21:38:55 2019 from 10.0.0.100
-------------------------------------------------------------- 09/25/19 21:43:36
terrance@Intrepid:~$
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, it doesn’t run the last `ls` command, it runs the last *command line* **beginning** with “ls” – try for example `lsb_release -d` followed by `!ls`.

Comment: @dessert Fine.....  You can have that one!  =)

Comment: I don't get the meaning of it. Can you explain more about it. What do you mean by it runs the last command line beginning with "ls"?
The example that I get is, firstly it runs "ls" then it shows the stuffs in that directory, then it runs "!ls" then it shows more stuffs than preview.
What actually happens?

Comment: @AlexPhang That's mean. The last command from `.bash_history`. When i tried `!ll` command, it run the last command of `history` and it executed. If i tried `!ls` command, it appears `event not found` cause i never use `ls` command. As Terrance's answer, you can check the command list from history to see what the last command of pointer your ran.

Answer (score 0):

Read `man bash`. It says, in part:

```
Event Designators
   An  event  designator  is a reference to a command line entry in the history list.  Unless
   the reference is absolute, events are relative to the  current  position  in  the  history
   list.

   !      Start  a  history  substitution, except when followed by a blank, newline, carriage
          return, = or ( (when the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin).
   !n     Refer to command line n.
   !-n    Refer to the current command minus n.
   !!     Refer to the previous command.  This is a synonym for `!-1'.
   !string
          Refer to the most recent command preceding the current position in the history list
          starting with string.
   !?string[?]
          Refer to the most recent command preceding the current position in the history list
          containing string.  The trailing ? may be omitted if string is followed immediately
          by a newline.
   ^string1^string2^
          Quick  substitution.   Repeat the previous command, replacing string1 with string2.
          Equivalent to ``!!:s/string1/string2/'' (see Modifiers below).
   !#     The entire command line typed so far.
```